# SoapUI Connection closed

Tags: soapui, soap-client

I got a few SOAP tests and unfortunately our test environment is very slow, that's why the default 15000ms are not enough I think.

Every once in a while, I get a `Connection closed` and it takes ages for the test to continue. I do have seen requests that took up to 7 seconds, guess 15 might be possible too then.

I changed the `Socket Timeout` of my test case to 25000 in the settings, but it didn't change anything, the console still says `Connection can be kept alive for 15000`.

```
10:20:43,347 DEBUG 
[SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] 
Sending request: POST /WebService/tcs HTTP/1.1
10:20:43,367 DEBUG 
[SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] 
Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
10:20:43,368 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be 
kept alive for 15000 MILLISECONDS
10:21:01,461 DEBUG 
[SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] 
Connection closed
```

After 1-3 minutes the test continues, so any hint where I can change those 15000?

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences -> HTTP Settings for Socket Timeout

Comment: I changed it already, that's what I meant with "changed the socket timeout of my test case". It does not change the timeout in the console. I already restarted soapUI as well. So you can confirm that this is the value that should be changed?